# Photoshop: Save for Web - Always same size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, images, save

I'm working as a product photographer and I have to edit around 30 images a day in Photoshop. Whenever I'm done editing, the images have to be saved for web and always with a width of 1080px.

My question: Is there a way (maybe a script) that sets the size for the images  to 1080px automatically when exporting them?
I know that you can save presets for the "save for web" feature, but that doesn't include the actual size, only the quality etc..

[image]

It would save me a lot of time, any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Im still using the legacy option.. no idea why they have changed it.

Comment: If you're working with Lightroom also, you could use this workflow: - Color adjustment and organisation inside of Lightroom - Retouching with Photoshop (Edit Original) - Export via Lightroom In Lightroom there is exactly the functionality you've requested. You can select all pictures to export and set a width they have to fit in. I'm also interested if there is a similar method with Photoshop.

Comment: I can't use Lightroom unfortunately, but thanks for the info

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *save for web (legacy)* is compatible with PhotoShop actions, which works like a script.

- Open a typical image you would want to perform the action on.
- Create a new action (in the actions panel) titled to your taste, something like '*1080px save for web*'
- Open the *image size* dialog and change the width to 1080px
- Click *ok*
- Now select *Save for web (legacy)* and adjust jpeg quality to preference.
- Click *save* and choose the folder you want the images to appear in.
- Close the image and answer *no* to saving it.
- Stop the action with the *stop* button in the actions panel.

You now have an action ready to perform on a group of images. To use it, place the images together in a folder you can find in PhotoShop and do the following:

- Open File -> Automate -> Batch...
- In the dialog that opens, you can change *Action* to the title of your just created action.
- Now choose the folder of images as *Source*
- Click *ok* and all of the images in your source folder should be resized to 1080px and saved out as jpegs.

You can add steps to this action if needed but that should roughly show you what's needed to automate performing actions on batch images in PhotoShop.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but definitely a good work-around. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that what you were looking for doesn't exist, so this is as close as you'll get for the outcome you need.